# The use of private $var slows down foreach in PHP (Symfony4 Console Command)

Tags: php, symfony

Given a Console Command with a dataset loaded from a database, my script crawls an API.
When "optimizing" my code, I noticed something some strange behaviour:

### Crawl Class / check_online

```
class Crawl {
    ...
    public function check_online($data){
        $settings = new Settings();
        $api = new RiotApi($settings);

        try {
            $game = $api->getCurrentGame($summoner->getSummonerId());
        } catch (RiotApiException $e) {
           throw new CrawlException($e->getMessage());
        }

        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

### Symfony Command

```
$apiCrawl = new Crawl($this->em, true);

foreach($dataset as $data){
    $online= $apiCrawl ->check_online($data);
}
```

This executes in about 1 second per  `$data`

Since the `$api` is used on multiple occasions, I tried to move it to the constructor of the `Crawl` class:

```
public function __construct(ObjectManager $em)
{
    $this->em = $em;
    $settings = new Settings();
    $this->api = new RiotApi($settings);
}
```

and updated the Symfony Command accordingly:

```
try {
    $game = $this->api->getCurrentGame($summoner->getSummonerId());
} catch (RiotApiException $e) {
    throw new CrawlException($e->getMessage());
}
```

now this needs about 10 seconds to execute. Is there anything wrong with this approach?

Comment: The code examples seem incomplete. Where is your loop (foreach) now?

Comment: The foreach does not change, only the `check_online` function basically from `$api->...` to `$this->api->...`